# How to track documents that are 30 days or older?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, document, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to track documents on sharepoint? 
I want to keep track of documents that are 30 days or older.
Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could try search.

Demo in my online environment.

[image]